# C++ Initialize class static data member

Tags: c++

I have a class which has a number of static function to perform some calculation. However, before the calculation, I need to pass in a data to initialize some of the static data members. Currently I have an init(data) function and a clearResource() function which should be called before and after the use of the class. Is there a better way of doing that?

For example:

```
classA(){
 static int a;
 static init(int b) {
    a = b;
 }
 static functionA(){
   //perform something based on value of a;
    switch(a){
    }
 }

}

int main(){
  classA::init(5);
  classA::functionA();
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: How the static functions can be dependent on your object state?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to use `init` and `clearResource` for each object of your class or only once for all objects.

Comment: Well if you have a function that is dependent on state then you should `wrap the state and the function` into its own class that encapsulates all this information. Then the constructor/destructor of this new class will handle all the above automatically.

Comment: You should really revisit your design. Note that just the description is a clear indication that your program will never support multithreading (a static variable has to be modified in each thread that uses `functionA`, both before entering and after completion. If a second thread tries to call the function while the first thread is inside, it will change the *global* while in the middle of the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David: Could you elaborate a bit on the multithreading part? I do not quite understand it. I didn't need to modify the value of the int a and it only needs to be init once at the beginning of the programme. Would that still give problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using static member functions : have your constructor initialize the data and the destructor clear the resources (see [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)). If the existing class cannot be changed, implement a helper class which calls `init` from its constructor and `clearResource` from its destructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this kind of design

```
class A()
{
public:
 static int a;
 static void functionA(int arg = A::a)
 {
  if(A::a != arg)
   A::a = arg;
  ...
 }
};

int A::a = 0;
int main()
{
 A::functionA();
}
```

Comment: Not nice by any means but fulfills the question requirements... I would ommit the default value if setting it is a requirement.

Comment: How can you free "a" afterwards, using this solution, supposing it is a (class-)object and not a primitive data type?

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the RAII concept: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635882/raii-tutorial-for-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104759/is-it-necessary-to-have-static-constructors-when-we-follow-the-raii-way-of-doi) questions.

Answer (score 1):

Make the member functions and data non-static, initialize in a constructor and free resources in the destructor. This will guarantee the correct sequence of calls: initialize - perform operations - free resources in the client code.

Comment: No, no, don't ensure uniqueness and don't consider the Singleton pattern.

Comment: there's usually little point in trying to enforce uniqueness, but many issues arise in the attempt... it's not worth it.

Comment: @DeadMG: It is unlikely that the OP needs uniqueness in this particular case so I removed the reference to Singleton. Although I wouldn't be so sure without seeing the actual (not example) code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using static members in this case.

This is your problem.  You have a class that does processing on some data.  That data, for whatever reason, needs to be shared across all instances of this processing class.  Ok then, we have a non-static solution!

```
class Data : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Data()
    {
        // initialise all of our data.
    }; // eo ctor
}; // eo class Data
```

Where you instantiate this class is up to you.  It could be a member of an application class that is run at start up, or part of some root.  It just needs to be accessible and does not need to be static nor a singleton.

```
class DataProcessor
{
private:
    Data& m_Data;

public:
    DataProcessor(Data& _data) : m_Data(_data)
    {
    }; // eo ctor
}; // eo class DataProcessor
```