# C++: I have this config class that I want to use between all my CPP files, how do I initialize it?

Tags: c++

```
class Config
{
    public:

        static int OUTPUT_TO_FILE;
        static int NEED_TO_TRAIN;
        static int NO_FILE_TRAIN;
        static int NEED_TO_TEST;
}
```

Above is my header.h file (i followed: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/11/05/252685.aspx)

and I want to be able to do things like Config.OUTPUT_TO_FILE = true or variable = Config.NO_FILE_TRAIN;

from any file that includes config.h

I have what I want to do is clear, Just want some variable shared throughout all my cpp files.

EDIT:
I'm having trouble compiling:

In my make file, I added:

```
hPif : src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o src/config.o # added the config part
    g++ src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o src/config.o -lfann -L/usr/local/lib -o hPif

config.o : src/config.cpp src/config.h
    g++ -c src/config.cpp

.
.
.
main.o: src/main.cpp src/config.h src/main.h src/hashes.h
    g++ -c src/main.cpp
```

config.cpp:

```
#include "config.h"

int OUTPUT_TO_FILE = false;
.
.
.
```

config.h:

```
class Config
{
    public:

        static int OUTPUT_TO_FILE;
.
.
.
```

Trying to call by:

```
#include "config.h"
...

            Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = true;
```

Error I get:

```
Undefined Symbols:
  "Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Initialize class static data member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192008/c-initialize-class-static-data-member)

Comment: These variables look like `bool`, not `int`.

Comment: @Beta: on many systems there is no `bool`. If want use platform independent code without many defines, easier to use other type than `bool`.

Comment: Where did you try it? `Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = true;` If in main.cpp you should add `#include "Config.h"`.

Comment: capital? I'm including the lowercase one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Header (Config.h):

```
#pragma once

class Config
{
public:
  static int OUTPUT_TO_FILE;
  static int NEED_TO_TRAIN;
  static int NO_FILE_TRAIN;
  static int NEED_TO_TEST;
};
```

Source (Config.cpp):

```
#include "Config.h"

int Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = 0;
int Config::NEED_TO_TRAIN = 0;
int Config::NO_FILE_TRAIN = 0;
int Config::NEED_TO_TEST = 0;
```

Usage (any.cpp):

```
#include "Config.h"

...
int variable = Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE;
...
```

Comment: Adding somedetails, as I am having trouble compiling.

Comment: @DerNalia: Config.h and Config.cpp are ready and fully detailed.

Comment: I think the problem may have my case... should be Config.h, not config.h

Comment: @DerNalia: Yes, in un*x match case is important.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your source files, add something like this:

```
int Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = 1;
```

Now, it will be initialized on program startup. Only do this in one source .cpp file, not in multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Because the class only has statics, you should be able to access them in any file which includes this header, for example..

foo.cpp

```
#include "Config.h"

void bar()
{
  Config::NO_FILE_TRAIN = 0; // set this value for example
}
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "Config.h"

void foo()
{
  Config::NEED_TO_TRAIN = 1; // set this value for example
}
```

Remember you must have an implementation file that is also compiled which actually defines the statics, i.e.

Config.cpp

```
int Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = 0; // initial value
:  //etc.
```

Comment: Adding some details, as I am having trouble compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement your Config class as a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Oh, and if you want to set `OUTPUT_TO_FILE = true`, you'd be better off declaring `OUTPUT_TO_FILE` as `bool`...